# Is D = $\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 1, 0 < z < 1 \}$ homeomorphic to $S^1$ and to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Is D = $\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 1, 0 < z < 1 \}$ homeomorphic to $S^1$ and to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$?

I define $S^1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$. I think that D is not compact because is limited but not closed, is that right? If it is, then it cannot be homeomorphic to $S^1$ because $S^1$ is indeed compact.

On the other hand I think it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ but I do not know how to prove it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about $D$ not being homeomorphic to $S^1$ (and about the reason why).

On the other hand$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&D&\longrightarrow&D\bigl((0,0),1)\setminus\{0\}\\&(x,y,z)&\longrightarrow&(x,y)\end{array}$$is a homeomorphism and I suppose that you know how to prove that $D\bigl((0,0),1)\setminus\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: I think I do not quite get it, can you show more steps?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: What is $D\bigl((0,0),1)\setminus\{0\}?$

Comment: @uniquesolution for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x^2+y^2<1$ the equation $z^2=1-x^2-y^2$ under the assumption $0<z<1$ always has a uniquesolution .

Comment: @Mark $\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\middle|\,0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1\right\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightening explanation, Peter King.

Comment: @LudovicoBessi 
$$\begin{array}{ccc}D\bigl((0,0),1\bigr)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\\(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)&\mapsto&\frac r{1-r}(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\end{array}$$is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos and is the composition  essentially the same as $D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{(0,0)\},(x,y,z)\mapsto (\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},\frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}})$ that yields the point of intersection of the line through "the pole" $(0,0,1)$ and the point of $D$ and the plane $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{(0,0)\}$?

Comment: sorry: I ment $D\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2},(x,y,z)\mapsto (\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}-1},\frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}-1})$ but this seems to establish a homeomorphism between $D$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\overline{D((0,0),1)}$

Comment: @PeterMelech That compostion of the map from my previous remark with $f$ can be extended continuously to $(0,0,1)$, providing a homeomorphism between the “northern hemisphere” of $S^2$ (with the “equator” excluded) and $\mathbb{R}^2$.